# Which post, exactly, is my father?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

> **I Am Your Father Hat** : ask, answer, or vote on the meta site.

Is there any way to check which answer or question that a member posted got him/her this hat ?

Comment: Is there a "Stalker" hat to be gotten from this?

Comment: What a sneaky way to receive this hat... ^^

Comment: @Roberrrt ... and a lot of votes ^^

Comment: I am trying to figure out where these hats appear.

Comment: I'm here for the irony hat.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Not directly from the 'hat' interface.

You can check it for yourself; you'll need to go to your profile on Meta, check the [All actions tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5558072/mrly?tab=activity&sort=all) and the [Votes tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5558072/mrly?tab=votes&sort=all) and figure out which action (posting or voting) came first (after the start of Winterbash 2016).

I can only see your post (this question), but voting records are anonymous so you won't see them for other users.

Comment: why i don't get the 24 or the 925 Hat of this question, or it take time, or what, thank you.

Comment: Questions on Meta don't count, unless the hat itself explicitly mentions it (like the I Am Your Father Hat).

Comment: what did you mean by **the hat itself explicitly mentions it (like the I Am Your Father Hat)**, i don't get it?

Comment: It explicitly mentions you have to do something on the Meta site: *ask, answer, or vote on the meta site*. Most other hats don't, so you have to do those actions on the main site.